# Как перенести все данные с Postman в axios для создания запроса?

Tags: javascript, axios, postman, next.js

Хочу сделать запрос с помощью axios. В Постмане все работает, но на axios есть проблемы с cors и авторизацией.

Пример кода -

```
    const data = {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [{ match: { domain: '' } }, { match: { full_text_ua: query } }],
        },
      },
    };
    const username = 'elastic';
    const password = 'search';
    const basicAuth = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64');
    return request.post(
      'https://new.sourcex.net:2443/api/console/proxy?path=%2Fmain_index%2F_search&method=GET',
      {
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
          Authorization: `Basic ${basicAuth}`,
          'kbn-xsrf': 'reporting',
        },
      }
    );
  };
```

Примеры ошибок -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://new.sourcex.net:2443/api/console/proxy?path=%2Fmain_index%2F_search&method=GET' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

xhr.js:178 POST https://new.sourcex.net:2443/api/console/proxy?path=%2Fmain_index%2F_search&method=GET net::ERR_FAILED
```

Стоит также сказать, что запрос идет на ссылку с Elastic Search.

Comment: приведите пример кода и ошибок

Comment: Проблема с CORS решается на стороне сервера.

Comment: Я тоже об этом думал, и воcпользовался jsonp, проблема с CORS ушла, но появилась проблема с авторизацией. Хотя, по идеи, не должно быть проблем.